# AlertDialog with ListView adapter

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, listadapter, listview-adapter

I try to do AlertDialog with ListView (adapter), and I get the Alert Dialog but I dont get the ListView, so my code is:

```
    public void namesDialog(View view){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_names_dialog, null);
    builder.setTitle("Names:");
    builder.setView(v);
    final ListAdapterDetailsNames adapter = new ListAdapterDetailsNames(this, mNames.getNames());
    mListViewTextNames.setAdapter(adapter);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}
```

What I should do to get the listView in the AlertDialog?

Thanks a lot for you help :)

Comment: Your list view is empty. So then you see no items.

Comment: What is your intention with mListViewTextNames? If it is a ListView then why not use that one?

Comment: @greenapps the mListViewTextNames this is the ListView..what I should do to fix it?

Comment: That i already told you: builder.setView(mListViewTextNames);

Comment: @greenapps i do this, but is not work..

Answer (score 0):

What is `mListViewTextNames`? You’re setting the adapter to a view that seems to exist even before you inflate `R.layout.list_view_names_dialog`... you almost certainly need to `findViewById()` within the inflated view to get the correct `ListView` to set the adapter on.

Comment: mListViewTextName is a ListView, so I try to get the ListView from layout: list_view_names_dialog

Comment: @Ei123456 do you see, though, that in the code you posted there's no reference to _finding_ `mListViewTextNames`? You take the trouble to call `inflate()` on `R.layout.list_view_names_dialog`, and this is your dialog's body view, but since you're not actually obtaining a reference to a ListView _from_ that body view, you must be setting the adapter on some _other_ ListView that's not in the dialog.

Comment: ok, now I am understand this and it's work fine!, thanks @Ben P.